# Meteor: Disable button based on data context?

Tags: meteor

I have a multi-tenant Meteor app and want to allow users with access to more than one organization's account to switch between organizations.

The ability to switch organizations is working, but I now want to be able to disable the `button` for the user's current organization, so they can not switch to the same organization they are already in.

Right now I'm trying to retrieve each button's value based on a `data-domain` attribute, but it comes back `undefined`. Also, `console.log(this);` comes back as `undefined` for the helper.

How would I get the data context to match the current button's value to the user's current organization?

Here's the template:

```html
<template name="switchAccountsModal">
  <div class="modal fade switchAccounts" id="switchAccounts" tabindex="-1" 
       role="dialog" aria-labelledby="switchAccounts">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Select an Organization</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="list-group">
            {{#each organizations}}
            <!-- {{activeOrg}} should render 'disabled' if this equals the 
                 user's current organization. -->
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item switchAccount" 
                    data-domain="{{this}}" {{activeOrg}}>{{this}}</button>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here's the helper:

```js
Template.switchAccountsModal.helpers({
  organizations: () => {
    var organizations = Meteor.user().organizations;
    console.log('organizations: ' + organizations);
    return organizations;
  },
  activeOrg: () => {
    console.log('activeOrg.this: ' + this);
    var currentOrg = Meteor.user().profile.currentOrg;
    var thisOrg    = $(this).data('domain');
    console.log('activeOrg.thisOrg: ' + thisOrg);
    return (this == currentOrg) ? {disabled: 'disabled'} : {};
  }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the geniuses in the Meteor Chef Slack channel (shout out to **brajt**, **stephendayta** & **michelfloyd**), I was able to work through and pass the correct data context. While there's a couple of options, the one that worked for me was to pass an argument `this` inside the spacebars tag like `{{activeOrg this}}` and then pick it up in the helper.

Here's the updated code if anyone else runs into this issue:

```
<template name="switchAccountsModal">
  <div class="modal fade switchAccounts" id="switchAccounts" tabindex="-1"
       role="dialog" aria-labelledby="switchAccounts">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
              aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Select an Organization</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="list-group">
            {{#each organizations}}
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item switchAccount"
                {{activeOrg this}}>
              {{this}}
            </button>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And the updated helper:

```
Template.switchAccountsModal.helpers({
  organizations: () => {
    var organizations = Meteor.user().organizations;
    return organizations;
  },
  activeOrg: (org) => {
    let currentOrg = Meteor.user().profile.currentOrg,
        thisOrg    = org;
    return (currentOrg === thisOrg) ? {disabled: 'disabled'} : {};
  }
});
```

The other option from **brajt** is to use `#each item in items` instead of `#each items`. I had tried that earlier, placing the actual button inside the `#each` variable into a subtemplate, but still wasn't able to pass the data context.