# Javascript - MeteorJS disable a button for a specific time depending on a variable that I could set manually

Tags: javascript, time, disabled-input

This is my problem: I have a submit button in JS on a page for my users.
I want to disable this button for different time (1 day/5 days/ 1 week) depending on a var that I collect from another radio button on my admin page. 
How could I do it?

---EDITED---

Please note that I need the function for a MeteorJS, javascript file.

So these are the Admin options:

```
<template name="dashboard">
<form name="notification">
                <label><input type="radio" name="timer" id="1day" value=1>1 day</label>
                <br>
                <label><input type="radio" name="timer" id="3day" value=3>3 days</label>
                <br>
                <label><input type="radio" name="timer" id="5day" value=5>5 days</label>
                <br>
                <label><input type="radio" name="timer" id="week" value=7>1 week</label>
                <br>
                <label><input type="submit" name={{data.profile.lastName}} id="timer"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i> Send</label>

            </form>
```

This options are relative to a user that I select before.
The timer has to be set for the access to a questionnaire.
I want to disable the button that lead to the questionnaire for the time I set as Admin.
For every user I've defined a Schema for the Answers I'm collectiong like this(is a Mongo DB collection)

```
 Schemas.Answers = new SimpleSchema({   createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue: function() {
          if (this.isInsert) {
            return new Date();
          }
        }   },   
answer: {
        type: [Number],
        optional: true   },   
userId: {
        type: String   },   
feel: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true   },   
timer: {
        type: Number,
        optional: true   } });
```

Note that I want to store the value selected by the admin in the timer field of the collection and then read it from the user side to set the button enable or disable.

THis is the button:

```
<h2>Do you want to continue to the questionnaire?</h2>
      <br>
      <a href="{{pathFor 'questionnaire'}}" class="btn btn-primary" id="goon">Go On</a>
```

Obviously the button has to be enable/disable even if the user will logout/leave the App(/webpage).

Comment: *"...1 day/5 days/ 1 week..."* Does this disabling of the button have to survive the user leaving your page and coming back to it?

Comment: Yes essentially the user could access to a questionnaire only if the button is active.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is doable, it would have to be done server side so that the "1 day/5 days" variable is implemented properly and stored when leaving the page/website.

Not sure if you have any knowledge about disabling elements in HTML since I can't see any code you have. (Any code you have would be useful to see to be able to help you more.) But simply disabling a button using javascript could be done like this:

```
document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
```

(assuming the button has an id of "button" ofcourse)

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible. what you need to do is trigger an ajax or a server side call and store it somewhere in the database

Now when you re-render the page just check if you have the value in the database and depending on that you can disable the button

If you share some code that would be helpful

to disable the button just use this

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled = true;
```

buttonId will be the id of the button

Comment: Well it's been a long time since I have  worked in meteor but from what I remember meteor js has  a watch of some kind which tells everyone that a database has been updated. 

So I think  the way you can achieve is you can keep on listening to some specific database field in the view and update the view the way you want

Comment: It will be wonderful if you could help me coding it so I could understand it better... Thanks

Comment: sure but let me go through some things and then I'll get back to you and if you are able to find the solution before I respond just post it over here so that other people can also benefit from it :)

Comment: @Jenny take  a look at this answer 

Maybe you will be able to get your answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159019/meteor-disable-button-based-on-data-context

Comment: That doesn't answer to my question!